# How to make a div fit the width of its contents without causing them to wrap, while being wider than is parent

Tags: html, css

See the code in this jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frpL3yr1/

The idea is that I want a bar of images at the top of the screen. The `img-wrapper` div will later be animated via javascipt to move to the left when you mouse over. For an example of what I am ultimately attempting to accomplish, see [this](https://designshack.net/tutorialexamples/photobanner/) page. The difference is that in mine, the animation will only run when moused-over.

The issue is that in my jsfiddle and the linked example, the width of the div containing the images is hard-coded. In my case, the css hard-codes the width of `img-wrapper` to 200%. I need my page to support an arbitrary number of images, so I need its width to be equal to that of the contents. The way my jsfiddle is implemented, if there are more images that can fit in `img-wrapper`, they will wrap to a new line.

What is the best way to go about fixing this?

Comment: can you use flexbox?

Comment: I have tried, but then all images become the same width, and distorted because their aspect ratio is not maintained

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach using `flexbox` and `animation`:

```
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.demo-ribbon {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vmin;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.img-wrapper {
  height: 70vmin;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: stretch;
}

img {
  flex: 1;
  object-fit: content;
  margin: 0 .2rem;
  width: 100vmin;
  height: 100%;  
}
.lead {
  animation: bannermove 12s linear 320ms infinite paused alternate;
}

.img-wrapper:hover .lead {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes "bannermove" {
 0% {
    margin-left: 0%;
 }
 100% {
    margin-left: -230%;
 }
}
```

You will need to add prefixes in order to work in all browsers especially `animation`

Further reading: https://devdocs.io/css/animation

working pen: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/KROvjx ;

Aspect Ratio: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp & https://css-tricks.com/aspect-ratio-boxes/

Hope helps! :)

Comment: It seems by using `flex:1` in the images, all images become the same width and height. The images may not all have the same aspect ratio, and may appear stretched or squished. An ideal solution would maintain the aspect ratio of the images. Also, your codepen doesn't seem to work properly on my machine (chrome 66). The images stretch out as they move

Comment: updated the pen @quantumbutterfly now only works on hover, you can still give them width: auto and height: auto, and they will have their original width and height. The reason behind the aspect radio is because the height of the parent container

Comment: Wow, thanks for putting the effort into this! The pictures still seem distorted though. This is a screenshot of what I'm seeing https://imgur.com/a/ICgoVzF

Comment: That's because the images have different aspect radios. So they won't shrink or expand and at the same time conserve the same aspect radio. I had updated my answer that's the best I can do

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox and animation with translate :)

```css
.demo-ribbon {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.demo-ribbon .img-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: stretch;
  margin-right: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.demo-ribbon .img-wrapper img {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  margin: 2px;
}
.demo-ribbon .img-wrapper img:first-child {
  animation: lefttoRight 25s linear 320ms infinite paused alternate;
}
.demo-ribbon .img-wrapper img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.demo-ribbon .img-wrapper:hover img {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes lefttoRight {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: -200%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="demo-ribbon">
  <div class="img-wrapper">
    <img class="lead" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
    <img src="http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/www-singapore-com/homepage/pagePropertiesImage/singapore.jpg.jpg">
    <img class="" src="https://www.s-ge.com/sites/default/files/cserver/styles/sge_header_lg/streamy/company/images/Hongkong-Fotolia-48687313-rabbit75-fot-282451.jpg?itok=ANpJxrgW">
    <img class="" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
    <img src="http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/www-singapore-com/homepage/pagePropertiesImage/singapore.jpg.jpg">
    <img class="" src="https://www.s-ge.com/sites/default/files/cserver/styles/sge_header_lg/streamy/company/images/Hongkong-Fotolia-48687313-rabbit75-fot-282451.jpg?itok=ANpJxrgW">
    <img class="" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
    <img src="http://static.asiawebdirect.com/m/phuket/portals/www-singapore-com/homepage/pagePropertiesImage/singapore.jpg.jpg">
    <img class="" src="https://www.s-ge.com/sites/default/files/cserver/styles/sge_header_lg/streamy/company/images/Hongkong-Fotolia-48687313-rabbit75-fot-282451.jpg?itok=ANpJxrgW">
    <img class="" src="https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/9a/e3/1d/freedom-tower.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```